# How to make Git Extensions browser show all commits like gitk --all

Tags: git, logging, commit, git-extensions, gitk

The Git Extensions repository browser seems to be more versatile than gitk in many ways.

[image]

However, my very favorite command line option for gitk is `--all`. `gitk --all` shows all commits, *including ones not reachable by any branch or tag*. This is very useful for understanding what actually happens in git. For instance after a rebase you can still see the original commits that have been copied and abandoned (and even return to them with `reset`).

[image]

Is there any way to make Git Extensions browser behave like `gitk --all` and show even unreachable commits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the risk of stating the now-obvious, as of 2018's 2.51.RC2 release and newer, commits that can be reached via the reflog can now be displayed in Git Extensions.  I'm not sure if this is exactly the same as `gitk --all`, but it does display many additional commits that are otherwise unreachable.

It appears to use `git log --reflog` behind the scenes.

The pull request is [here](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/pull/4321), and it was released with [2.51.RC2](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/releases/tag/v2.51.RC2).

[image: Image of the "Show reflog references" option in the View menu in Git Extensions]

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is no. However, you can open `gitk --all`, with a little work.

If you're willing to sacrifice performance, you can get some more information by changing the following in Settings > Settings > Git extensions > Performance. Check "show current working changes in revision graph". I've left that off and ended up using the Hotkeys settings tab.

- Hotkeys > RevisionGrid. Make sure "ShowAllBranches" has a shortcut key. It usually is Ctrl+Shift+A.
- Hotkeys > Browse. Make sure GitGitK has a shortcut key. I've used Ctrl+K. It brings up gitk from inside Git Extensions. However, you then have to view all branches manually, so I'm not sure how useful you'll find it on its own.
- Finally, I think the one you'll really like is the Scripts tab. You will need to manually add a Gitk --all script there, but then you can assign a hotkey to it. You then have gitk --all from inside Git Extensions.

Have fun :)

Apparently, there is also [a feature request that is 3 months old](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/1737) for precisely this ;)

Comment: Thanks, but I already had "show current working changes in revision graph" and "ShowAllBranches" turned on, and the result is as above, no unreachable commits are shown. Using Script to bring up `gitk --all` from Git Extensions, was a creative idea, but it doesn't really make the Git Extensions browser itself behave as gitk --all :)

Comment: No it doesn't. But it does get you to a right-click or keyboard shortcut away from that view. Yes, it is an extra window, but apart from that, it doesn't look like its possible.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to something like "git reflog". That should show all of your commits that have been made, even if you accidentally do a reset later and lose previous commits. You can recover "lost" commits that way. I don't believe their is button in GIT extensions to show that information.

You usually have to do a git reflog in the command line to find the commit hash, then check out a branch with that hash. I have used that for recovering commits with merges gone bad before.

Comment: I would like to have a graphical representation of the unreachable commits.

Comment: https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/2303    Just added a feature request for GIT extensions. I guess I could try to code it myself and do a pull request.

Comment: That would be a great addition to Git Extensions!